# Understanding pxe config?

Tags: pxe-boot

```
label DB
  kernel vmlinuz
  append initrd=initrd-6.2.img ramdisk_size=4196000 ip=dhcp ks=http://bmd/BaseServer/nua-6.cfg ksdevice=link text nofb biosdevname=0
```

I am trying to understand how to interpret the pxe config.

1. What does kernel vmlinuz mean ?

Does it mean to pull the kernel called vmlinuz from the tftp server ?

2. What does `append` mean ?
3. What is `ksdevice`?
4. What is `nofb` ?
5. What is `biosdevname` ?

Comment: So.. No actual problem to solve other than you don't know what this means?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The `kernel` line indicates which file to boot as the OS kernel.
2. `append` is, like it sounds, just the flag to indicate the start of a list of options that are appended to the kernel boot command.
3. `ksdevice` indicates the network device that kickstart/anaconda will use to do its stuff.  Apparently this is deprecated in current versions of Anaconda according to the [documentation](https://rhinstaller.github.io/anaconda/boot-options.html#ksdevice)
4. `nofb` According to this [source](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/AnacondaIsoLinux0ptions),

> nofb* -- Do not load the VGA16 framebuffer required for doing text-mode installation in some languages.

5. `biosdevname` enables consistent network device naming.  Rather than the 'ethX' scheme that is based on the order that the devices are activated, use the device's interface name e.g. ens160, enp0s25, etc. for device names that are based off of where the devices are located on the system, which is consistent across reboots no matter how many additional devices are added later.

More about [Syslinux](http://www.syslinux.org/wiki/index.php/Config) on the Syslinux wiki.